# Issues configuring the access ports (ubiquiti)

Tags: networking, lacp, vswitch, ubiquiti, rstp

We currently have issues configuring the access ports for our servers on our rack switches(USW-EnterpriseXG-24).

Since we've learned that ubiquiti does currently not support switch stacking (vswitch) - we'd like to know how we can accomplish network resiliency for our servers?

Please could you suggest a way like

- rack-switches with RSTP
- servers connected to both switches
- operating system configured with "active/passive" or "lacp"?

Is there a way to accomplish switch stacking or is this feature currently planned in the medium term?